# Strangeness with Symlinks and Relative Paths

Tags: directory, symlink, directory-structure

Could someone please explain this to me?  I'm having trouble understanding how this is set up and why it behaves the way it does.

I wanted to see where `zsh` is *actually* installed on a machine that I use.  So I used `ls` to find where the symlink points.

```
$ ls -l /bin/zsh
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root          14 Dec  1  2011 /bin/zsh -> ../sfw/bin/zsh*
```

When I saw this, I thought, "Okay, the symlink uses a relative path. No big deal."

But if I then try to `cd` directly to what *should* be where the relative path points, I get this:

```
$ cd /bin/sfw/bin
cd: no such file or directory: /bin/sfw/bin
```

However, if I specifically type *this*

```
$ cd ../sfw/bin
```

when `/bin` is the working directory, then it works.  And then I also get this:

```
$ pwd
/usr/sfw/bin
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/bin` is probably a symlink to `/usr/bin` on your system. If that were true then:

```
/bin/../sfw/bin/zsh
```

would actually be the same as

```
/usr/bin/../sfw/bin/zsh
```

which reduces to

```
/usr/sfw/bin/zsh
```

which is where `zsh` actually lives. Note that what you tried, which was

```
/bin/sfw/bin
```

does not correspond to any path that you actually could see on the system. The correct way to resolve a relative path (`../sfw/bin/zsh`) given the absolute path path that forms the base for that relative path (`/bin`) is to concatenate them together as `/bin/` + `../sfw/bin/zsh` → `/bin/../sfw/bin/zsh`.